# Curl request in Python by urllib or urllib2

Tags: android, python, post, curl, urllib2

I need to transform curl POST request into python urllib or/and urllib2 POST request

**THATS CURL**:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add" \
-H "Accept-Language: en-US" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" \
-H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--user-agent "com.foursquare.android:2013040200:20130402:4.2.2:GT-I9100:release" \
--data "ll=55.828299%2C49.081782&llAcc=56.0&venueId=5192088a498edf76505871fe&shout=&broadcast=public&oauth_token=blahblahblah&v=blablabla"
```

**MY PYTHON CODE**:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add'

values = {
  'll' : '55.828299%2C49.081782',
  'llAcc' : '56.0',
  'venueId' : '5192088a498edf76505871fe',
  'shout' : '',
  'broadcast' : 'public',
  'oauth_token' : 'blahblahblah',
  'v' : 'blablabla',
}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)

req = urllib2.Request(url, data)  # POST request doesn't not work
req.add_header("Accept-Language", "en-US")
req.add_header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
req.add_header("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.add_header("User-Agent","com.foursquare.android:2013040200:20130402:4.2.2:GT-I9100:release")

urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

---

That's rising error:

```
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

But cURL code working well.

Comment: 'll' parameter in values is manually encoded and you are encoding it again with => data = urllib.urlencode(values)

Comment: ll parametr is in data, so i encode it only once...
I don't see where I encoding it second time.

Comment: I mean, you have written %2C to encode character ',' and then you do urllib.urlencode(values) which is going to encode '%2C' into '%252C'

Comment: so how i can change it, to working version ?

Comment: Just initialize 'll': '55.828299,49.081782'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [moliware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340298/moliware) said, all is right except 
'll' : '55.828299%2C49.081782',
it should be :
'll': '55.828299,49.081782'